# Blender's "stdio.h" not found anywhere

Tags: osl

Trying to run some OSL scripts for Blender 2.83 on mac. Never tried it before and having troubles with it.

Any script I try to run gives same error

```
ERROR: /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.83/scripts/addons/cycles/shader/stdcycles.h:31: error: error: could not find include file: stdosl.h
Error: OSL script compilation failed, see console for errors
```

Where "stdosl.h" is supposed to be? I can't find anywhere on my drive.
Downloaded fresh build of Blender - no such file as well in any directories.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Downloaded Win version, copied missing file, works fine. Weird.